# Derivation of t(n-1) distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

While trying to prove that

$\displaystyle \frac{\bar{X}\,-\,\mu}{S/\sqrt{n}}\sim t_{n-1}$ I came across a manipulation that I can not seem to understand the reasoning behind it.

Why does 
$$\frac{\bar{X}\,-\,\mu}{S} \cdot \sqrt{n}  = \frac{ \frac{\bar{X}\,-\,\mu}{σ}{\sqrt{n} }}{{\sqrt{ \frac{(n-1)\cdot S^2} {σ^2 }/(n-1)}}}\quad \text{?}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

$$\displaystyle \frac{\bar{X}\,-\,\mu}{S} \sqrt{n}= \displaystyle \frac{\frac{\bar{X}\,-\,\mu}{\sigma}}{\frac{S}{\sigma}} \sqrt{n}= \displaystyle \frac{\frac{\bar{X}\,-\,\mu}{\sigma}\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\frac{S^2}{\sigma^2}}} = \displaystyle \frac{\frac{\bar{X}\,-\,\mu}{\sigma}\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\dfrac{\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}}{n-1}}} $$

Comment: could you explain how you expand the square root on the 3rd part?

Comment: I multiply and divide by $(n-1)$ assuming $n \not=1$